# Trigger server-sent-event on GET / POST in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, react-redux, server-sent-events

I have a mock backend in nodejs/express that I need to get working.  There is an SSE setup like this:

```js
app.get("/api/sseConnect" ,(req, res) => {

  headers = {
    "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
    Connection: "keep-alive",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Cache-Control": "no-transform",
  };
  res.writeHead(200, headers);

  let intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(Math.random())}\n\n`);
  }, 5000);

  res.on("close", () => {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    res.end();
  });

});
```

This is working great - the client hits this route, the connection is established, and the client recieves the message every 5 seconds.

There are other standard routes, which when accessed, modify some data in the database.  Once the data is modified, I need to send a server-sent-event.  So for example:

```js
app.post("/api/notifications/markasread", (req, res) => {

  let { ids } = req.body;
  ids.forEach(id => database.notifications[id].read = true) // or whatever

  // Send a server-sent-event with some information that contains id, message status, etc

})
```

I know this seems really silly (why not just send a response???), but this is the way that the live api is set up - there is no response from this post route (or certain other routes).  They needs to trigger an SSE, which is listened for on the front end with an [`EventSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) instance.  Based on what is heard in the `eventSource.onmessage` listener, a whole bunch of things happen on the front end (react-redux).

How can I 'hijack' the SSEs and trigger a response from a standard POST or GET route?

Comment: Since you are using a database, the POST call would update the notification count. On SSE API add logic to check the database on your 5-sec interval and respond to the client with your desired JSON output.

Comment: So I managed to get this working in the way you suggested.  However one thing I don't like about it is that it requires me writing a whole new chain of logic for every possible thing that can happen that modifies data.  I wonder if there's a way to do it directly from any given route's `(req, res) => {}` callback?